# Select statement returning empty list when there are rows in the table

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to build an automated report. Most of the data is being pulled through web scraping before I start my shift. The program then enters a loop where it checks for data every five minutes using the function provided below. There is one data set that I have been unable to scrape so I set up a excel workbook that I can paste the data in to then insert the data in to my database.

Using a cli query `SELECT * FROM TableName` it returned `5160 rows in set (0.089 sec)` at the same time as the python program was getting an empty list.

```py
def checkData():
    try:
        db.c.execute('SELECT * FROM TableName')
    except mariadb.Error as error:
        printc(f"Error: {error}")

    data = db.c.fetchall()
    rcount = db.c.rowcount
    logging.debug(f'No data found: {data} num rows: {rcount}')
    print(data)
    if len(data)>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Logging output

```
2019-06-28 09:00:20,817 - DEBUG - No data found: [] num rows: 0
```

When I execute only the checkData function it returns True if there is data. Earlier in the program there is a `db.c.execute('DELETE FROM TableName')` statement. Is it possible that the database is caching old responses and what would be the best way to get it to inform me when it is no longer empty?

**Additional Information:**

Include Statement

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
```

db is an object of

```
class DatabaseConnection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'host'
        self.passwd = 'password'
        self.db_conn = mariadb.connect(user='user', password=self.passwd, host=self.url, database='DatabaseName')
        self.c = self.db_conn.cursor()
```

Comment: Which mysql client are you using ?

Comment: Why do you log failure in any case?

Comment: Does this method return `True` or `False` in the end? I'm wondering that maybe the `fetchall` running *before* `rowcount` might have an impact on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `rowcount` works as expected (tried it myself, even after the `fetch_all`). So, your query is most likely returning nothing.

Are you sure you have a valid connection to your database in your python script?

Comment: `if len(data)>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False`
I am checking for the len(data) as my return condition and the data that is being assigned when outputted shows an empty list `[]`. rcount was just added later as a check for extra information when I ran in to issues.

Answer (score -1):

Assign the result from the query to a variable and use the fetchall() method on that variable.

```
def checkData():
    try:
        result = db.c.execute('SELECT * FROM TableName')
    except mariadb.Error as error:
        printc(f"Error: {error}")

    data = result.fetchall()
```

Comment: Looking at the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html), you don't necessarily need to store the `execute` in a variable to run `fetchall()`.

Comment: That causes an error

`
    data = result.fetchall()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
`

Also all of the example code I have seen use cursor.fetch See: https://pynative.com/python-mysql-select-query-to-fetch-data/

Comment: Yes, db.c is the cursor